# How to correct work with char array in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have some api function that needs char*** as input parameter.
So, char*** is array of array of char*.

How it is possible to correct set this char*** ?

```
vector<string> theAttributeValues;
...
char*** listOfListOfValues;
char** listOfValues;
char* stringValue;
for (int i=0; i<theAttributeValues.size(); i++)
{
  stringValue = theAttributeValues[i].c_str();
  listOfValues = (const char**)stringValue;
  listOfListOfValues = new const char**(listOfValues);
}
```

And how to read any char* of this char*** ?

```
for (int i=0; i<listOfListOfValues.size(); i++)
{
  char* strValue = listOfListOfValues[i][0];
  cout<<to_string(i)<<" value:"<<strValue<<endl;
}
```

Comment: `char ***` looks like a 2D array of strings, but `vector<string>` is 1D.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, function wroten to set list of strings, but in my situation its sets only one string, so 2D always will be equal to 1.
In second code example I'm reading only [0] elements.

Comment: Ok, next question: does the function receiving the array also takes the size?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, function also gets size of ListOfListOfValues and working with this in its own way. There is no problem with those function.
The problem is to set this char*** to pass in this function.

char*** must looks like:
ListOfListOfValues[0][0]
ListOfListOfValues[1][0]
ListOfListOfValues[2][0]
etc...
second dimension can be only [0], its okay.

Comment: Have you actually defined the confusingly named `sizeOf` function, or are you misspelling and misusing `sizeof`?

Comment: @molbdnilo I'm using sizeof, its misspelling, sorry, I will edit

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays. Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com); most of it applies to C++ as well.

Comment: `sizeof(listOfListOfValues)` is not the number of elements, it is `sizeof(vector<string>)`, which is constant. You want `listOfListOfValues.size()`. (You can't get the structure you want from a `vector<string>`. My advice would be to start over.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for advice, I will use it. Editing.

Comment: `I have some api function` Could you tell what "api function" is that? from what library? how it is named ? where is it from?

Comment: @KamilCuk this is closed corporate library, sorry, I cant tell. This works fine with those parameters. The problem is to prepare them.

Comment: So what can you tell more about the "api function" parameter? Does it has to be an array of `char **`, if so, what size, or just a single pointer? Will the pointer or array elements be assigned or mutated, in any of the dimensions? Does the elements on which dimensions have to be dynamicallly, or statically alocated? If dynamic, with `new` or with `new[]` or with `malloc`, and if so, with what size? Should the array's (if any) terminated with a sentinel value, if so, what value? It's just too broad, you have to define what "correct" in "correct set this to char***" means.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, its must be array of char** (char***). The size of this array is calculated somehow inside of function. I can't see source files. I know that this is works. Many people using this function. 
The size of char*** can be declared any opportunity. In my situation its need to set char*** like: listOfListOfValues[0][0], listOfListOfValues[1][0], listOfListOfValues[2][0]. Changes only first quotes index, second is equal 0 every time.

Comment: This is a terrible code smell. See https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want this.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> values = {"a", "b", "c"};

    std::vector<char **> x;
    std::vector<char *> y;

    x.reserve(values.size());
    y.reserve(values.size());

    for (std::string &str : values)
        x.push_back(&y.emplace_back(str.data()));
    
    char ***array = x.data();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
        std::cout << array[i][0] << '\n';
}
```

I'm assuming that only `arr[i][j]` (the strings) need to be null-terminated, and not `arr[i]` and `arr` (the pointer arrays).

Comment: Thank you! This part very helpful for me!